# We landed a man on Mars, and then all wars ceased

Tags: story-identification, mars

I've been trying to remember a short story.

The trick ending was that when we landed a man on Mars, all wars immediately stopped on Earth... but then we were about to land a man on Venus which would (presumably) have the effect of ending love.

Most likely a "Golden Age" sci-fi story. Told with a Venus landing newscast going on in the background.

Comment: Which war? Could you be more specific with the details?

Comment: All wars.  Man became peaceful.  Having touched Mars, there was no war anymore.  The implication being that once we touched down on Venus (I think the people in the story were watching a news cast?), there would be no love...

Comment: The story isn't the newscast.  There's just a newscast about the Venus landing going on in the background.

Comment: I can't name the story, but I think I remember it.  Early on, it follows a werewolf who, after July 16, 1969, stopped changing with the full moon -- then went on to join the Mars mission.

Comment: This may have something to do with the roman god mars being the god of war, and the roman god venus being the goddess of love

Comment: I spent a while searching for this story, but I was unable to find it. When was it published? Can you add as many details as you can recall to the body of the question? That might help people answer it. Even phrases, if specific enough, might be helpful. If it was published recently and had a Golden-Age feel, it might be from the noxious Vox Day and his Castalia House company.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't have anything about Venus, but the Mars part sounds exactly like "Moonrise" by Dorothy J. Heydt. I read it in "The Best of Marion Zimmer Bradley's Fantasy Magazine" (1994), but it was [originally published](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54856) in the summer 1988 issue of Marion Zimmer Bradley's Fantasy Magazine.

The [synopsis](http://kithrup.com/%7Edjheydt/index.html) from Heydt's website says:

> The first manned Moon landing changed Vilkas's life. Now, while war threatens, he's waiting for the Mars landing.

Vilkas, the main character, was a werewolf, and the story (after a brief intro) flashes back to him preparing to transform, the night of the first full moon after the moon landing -- but he didn't transform, that night or ever again. Another character complains about humanity's arrogance in setting foot on another world, saying they've "taken all the magic out of the moon."

Many years later, worldwide tensions are nearly ready to erupt into war. Vilkas is a senator, chairman of the Space Committee; and he's in the press room at NASA, counting down the minutes until the first manned landing on Mars... and he's watching the headlines, waiting for the fighting to stop.

Comment: Correct. Marion's then-editor (whose name I don't recall) was experienced with publishing but knew nothing about fantasy or SF. She came to Marion with the MS. of this story and said, "Is there a page missing here? Because I don't understand it." Marion carefully explained. This was the same editor who looked at the diploma from Miskatonic University hanging on Marion's wall, and asked, "Is that where you did your undergraduate work?" She was later replaced by another editor who knew both editing and SFF.

Comment: If anybody wants to read "Moonrise," you can find it on my website, http://www.kithrup.com/~djheydt/ , in a collection of shorts called *Stories You Never Heard Of,* along with a lot of other stuff I wrote back in the 1980s and -90s.